Per the Chatam Sofer is there Modernly a Dual Purpose served by the Insertion of the Words "Hashem S'fatai Tiftach"?
The words "Hashem Sfatai Tiftach ..." are uttered before T'filla. Why? Per the Chatam Sofer (Brachot 4b) it's to unlock the paralysis.


Loosely translated - ... the reason for opening the prayer with Hashem Sfatai Tiftach is because of the trembling and fear of the awe of the King of Kings, God. For even if his prayer is arranged      and set, when he stands in front of God his knees/legs knock together and all his bones are in fear, and this removes (most) of the ability to speak. Therefore, he prays Hashem Sfatai Tiftach.

Thus, per the C"S, the foregoing opening words are a supplication to unlock the paralysis and be able to pray.
Most are arguably out of touch with this awe-lock today (how many people are inarticulate and locked in fear before praying?). The foregoing words nowadays could thus serve a related, dual purpose - not only does the supplication request an unlock per the original enactment, but more significantly, it likely revives within the petitioner an awareness of an antecedent awe-lock state which necessitated the enactment (an awe-lock redux).
Are there are similarly situated rabbinic enactments that modernly (during periods of spiritual decline) serve a dual purpose (the original purpose PLUS the implicit modern recognition that the basis for the original enactment assumed an antecedent metziuot that may no longer exist and which we thus should first strive to achieve)?
In the absence of the awe-lock are the words Hashem Sfatai Tiftach desirable at that point in prayer? Are they a hefsek per C"S between gueala and tefila for those not locked in awe?
(I feel this discussion of awe-lock relates to Rav Chayim Brisk's famous piece on needing a basic threshold 'kavana' when praying -to stand before God; anything less is a nonstarter in the sense that one has not even performed a maaseh tefila).

This is a great question! I'm not sure I agree with your premise, though- do we really say H' sifatay teeftach "to remind us that we should be locked in fear in the first place"? And if so, how do you know that?

@ יהושע ק thanks for your thoughts. Let me tweak the question.
